# how can I read rss feed using Yii

Tags: rss, yii, feed

I want read the other site's feeds in my website using `yii` framework how I can do it? if `yii` is not good, what's your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii is a framework - just tool in your hands. You can do whatever you want.
As I know threre are no extensions to parse RSS. You can use [lib](http://rssphp.net/) within your Yii project or just standalone.